# Android alt-beacon model distance calculations

Tags: distance, altbeacon

Android Alt-Beacon library distance calculation code uses model-distance-calculation.json file to find model specific equation coefficients.
 The default list only contains 4 models.
 Is there a more extensive list of models and their coefficients available somewhere? 
 

Thanks 

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no large list of beacon distance calculation coefficients for the thousands of Android devices out there.

I am the one who came up with the idea of a model-distance-calculations.json file to serve as a database for these coefficients in the Android Beacon Library.  I had hoped that submissions from the community would lead to many popular Android devices being included.  Unfortunately, taking the measurements and doing the calculations has proven to be a more difficult hurdle for folks in the community, and as a result, the database is quite limited.  Sorry!